# How does NodeJS handle persistent connections without WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm really new to NodeJS (and I'm sorry if I sound naive about some stuff) and I've been digging into the source code of the example [Chat Application](http://github.com/ry/node_chat).

However, I'm having trouble understanding one thing. I know that WebSockets helps handle persistent full-duplex bi-directional connections. But how does NodeJS manage a persistent connection in the aforementioned chat application without the use of WebSockets? And if NodeJS **can** handle a persistent bi-directional connection, what exactly is the function of integrating something like Socket.IO in Node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides WebSockets you can use [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_polling#Long_polling) technique to create persistent connection between server and client.

> Long polling is a variation of the
>   traditional polling technique and
>   allows emulation of an information
>   push from a server to a client. With
>   long polling, the client requests
>   information from the server in a
>   similar way to a normal poll. However,
>   if the server does not have any
>   information available for the client,
>   instead of sending an empty response,
>   the server holds the request and waits
>   for some information to be available.
>   Once the information becomes available
>   (or after a suitable timeout), a
>   complete response is sent to the
>   client.

However it's not as efficient as WebSockets, but it's used because it works in every browser unlike WebSockets. Try to look at this [article](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket):

> Reducing kilobytes of data to 2
>   bytes…and reducing latency from 150ms
>   to 50ms is far more than marginal. In
>   fact, these two factors alone are
>   enough to make WebSocket seriously
>   interesting to Google.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the chat application.  And I don't see a link for a hosted demo.

NodeJS is a server-side technology.  It has no trouble with native sockets.  Socket.IO is a combination client-side and server-side technology.  It just happens to use NodeJS for the server side.  The beauty of it is that it presents a common communications API on the client side, regardless of what features the browser actually has.

Comment: The Chat Application is hosted at [chat.nodejs.org](http://chat.nodejs.org)
So you mean it's possible to simulate all functionality provided by Socket.Io by utilizing only NodeJS?

Comment: No, that's not what I was trying to say.  I mean, you could, by rewriting socket.io.

Comment: That chat application uses long polling.  You can do long polling with lots of server-side technologies; not just NodeJS.

Comment: Oh, I did not know it used long polling! Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: It uses long polling as one of it's fallback technologies.  It tries WebSockets, and if that's not supported tries FlashSockets, and if that's not supported, falls back to various old school Comet methods.

Comment: @mikermcneil, I don't think so.  It uses long polling.  Have a look at the source code:  https://github.com/ry/node_chat/blob/master/client.js

Comment: socket.io does the things you described, but that chat app does not use socket.io.

Comment: Right, I'm talking about socket.io in general.  Sorry for the confusion.