# Can't get simple ajax example to work

Tags: ajax, file, text

I'm trying to learn some ajax. And I'm trying to get ajax to read a text file asynchronously.

heres my code:

```
<html>
<head> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var http = false;

    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
      http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
       http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    function replace() {
      http.open("GET", "tester.txt", true);
      http.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4) {
          document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = http.responseText;
        }
      }
      http.send(null);
    }
  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<p><a href="javascript:replace()">Replace Text</a></p> 

<div id="foo" style="background: #CFEBFF; border: 2px solid #0090F4; padding: 4px"> 
  Hello, world!
</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

When ever I click the link i gave up there. It just shows a blank. Yet my text file in the same directory (called tester.txt) holds some information. Help please? Thank you.

Comment: Start with fiddler or firebug (or similar) to see the request and response.

Comment: weird, I got it to work on firefox, but it didnt work on my google chrome. I have ubuntu linux 10.10. Maybe thats the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're really committed to learning how to do this the hard way, I would really recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this. It handles all that weird browser difference for you with [a great library for AJAX requests](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). To make the call you want, it would be as simple as:

```
$.get('tester.txt').success(function (receivedData) {
  //do something with receivedData
});
```

If you are looking to do this the hard way, well, best of luck to you. You could look at how [jQuery implements it](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js) for some clues, lines 7442 to 7980.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know that jquery is asynchronous. Question: I'm trying to extend this further to make a simple online chat program. Can jquery poll mysql database for chat information? What would be the best way to go about this? Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question. You'd probably want some sort of client-server system with a persistent connection using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [long polling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428450/how-does-nodejs-handle-persistent-connections-without-websockets/5429752#5429752). On the client-side with jQuery, it's a matter of getting AJAX calls into the proper loops to call to the server looking for new chat information.